# Are these jumbled tenses?

Tags: tense-agreement

> Several studies demonstrated that older crop varieties typically have
>   lower yields but substantially higher nutrient levels than modern
>   varieties. For example, some researchers ***found*** that breeding to
>   “improve” wheat varieties over the past 130 years, during which yields
>   of grain per acre ***have tripled***, ***had reduced*** levels of iron
>   by 28 percent and zinc by roughly a third. Similarly, milk from modern
>   Holstein cows, in which breeders ***have managed*** to more than
>   triple the daily yield since 1950, ***has*** considerably less
>   butterfat and other nutrients than that from older, less “improved”
>   types of cows.

If the choice of each tense is awkward how would you change it?

Comment: Yes, they are somewhat jumbled. If that research was recent, it could say **have found** and **has reduced**.  The present perfect could be used throughout.  Since the author says "the past 130 years" and not "the preceding 130 years", the implication is that the research is current research.

Comment: I would prefer simple past for *tripled* and *managed*. Just remove the *have* from before each of those.